# VSCode terminal - ng: command not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, angular-cli

I'm trying to use the Angular CLI in the VSCode terminal, but I'm getting the following error:

```
$ ng new app
bash: ng: command not found
```

[image: Screenshot showing same as above resulting from a MINGW bash prompt]

Comment: In an environment where `ng` works, run `type ng`. If it says it's an external command, make sure that command's location is in your PATH. If it says it's a function or alias, make sure the place that function or alias is defined is sourced into your shell.